# Error breaking role inheritance on SharePoint list item using PnPJS

Tags: typescript, typeerror, sharepoint-online, spfx, pnp-js

I am using PnPJS in an SPFx webpart in which I have a method to set custom item level permissions on specific items in several lists. My code is as follows:

```
let listIds: string[] = [
    "LISTGUID1",
    "LISTGUID2"
];

for (const listId of listIds) {
    const listItems: Item[] = await sp.web.lists
        .getById(listId)
        .items
        .filter(`LookupFieldId eq ${lfId}`)
        .get();

    if (Validate.ArrayWithElements(listItems)) {
        for (const item of listItems) {
            await item.breakRoleInheritance(false);
            await item.roleAssignments.add(userId, roleDefId);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error on following line:

`await item.breakRoleInheritance(false, false);`

The error message is as follows:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: item.breakRoleInheritance is not a function

It also doesn't work when I cast the result explicitly to type `Item`. The `Item` class extends `SharePointQueryableShareableItem` and `SharePointQueryableShareableItem` extends `SharePointQueryableSecurable`. The method is defined in the latter.

Answer (score 3):

I have just resolved the issue by adding the imports in my library component:

```
import "@pnp/sp/security/web";
import "@pnp/sp/security/list";
import "@pnp/sp/security/item";
```

Source: https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs/issues/1250